# Is it normal that the tyre fits effortless the rim?

Tags: tire, rims, puncture

I've been constantly having problems with my wheel going flat. I couldn't find anything on the rim but I changed the rim tape and I bought a new tyre.

The old tyre was a bit worn. It was also fitting the rim too easy, something I was attributing to the fact that it was old and also that I've been changing the tube a lot.
Nevertheless, now I noticed that the new tyre also goes a bit too easy, as in, I didn't even have to use any tool to put it.

I am sure they are the right size and I don't see any evident sign in the rim to make me think it is not usable anymore, although it is a bit hit here and there but nothing particular as to make anyone think it shouldn't work fine.

Is this normal? Should I check something else?

EDIT: 
The  tyre size is 37-622. It is a city (Grandma/Grandpa-like bike).

Comment: Could you  please use Edit to add what tyre size you have bought?  Is it possible you bought 28" tyres for a 700c wheel ?

Comment: As long as the tyre is well seated on the rim when inflated, you should be ok.

Comment: @Criggie Sure Thing, I can check properly when I got to the bike again and edit. But you made me noticed that I didn't really know the wheel properties, I rather kept buying tyres based on the size of the first one the bike had, and the size is 37-622.

Comment: I have never had a tire that went on easily. I have used narrower tires than the original without a problem. I'd say air it up slowly. If it stays on, you should be ok. The bead should not seat if it is the wrong size.

Comment: The bigger the tyre's volume, the easier it is to get a tyre on/off without tools.  If it was a skinny road tyre in 23-25 I'd worry more, but a 37mm tyre gives a lot more slack when deflated.

Comment: Mounting without tools , yes, unmounting without tools no

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all tires are hard to put on (depends on type) and rims also have a variation in size (both between different types of rims and sample to sample variation within one model). In fact, I'd say many tires for urban and mountain bikes can be mounted without tools if you know how to. There are obviously counterexamples that are notorious for being tight.

Unless you can get the tire **off** easily and without tools too, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I guess the rim model can be quite different, and that would make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it should be possible to mount/unmount any tire without tools: The bead has a diameter that is smaller than the outer diameter of the rim, but also larger than the diameter of the bottom of the rim. Thus, you can partially get the bead over the top of the rim in one place by pushing it down to the bottom everywhere else.

With real tires, the method above is tricky, though. Tires have some amount of stiffness that counteracts your attempts to push the bead low. So, the stiffer the tire, the harder to put it on / take it off.

Now, wide tires usually have a relatively soft and long flank (the part on the side which flexes as you ride), so they are easy to (un-)mount. For a "Grandma/Grandpa-like" tire, I would expect to be able to (un-)mount it without tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean *effortless*, i.e. the tire slips onto (or off) the rim with almost no force, there may be something wrong.

If it is just *easy* to get the tire on the rim, that's OK. There is some variation in time bead sizes and rim wall heights that make some tires easy to install and some difficult.

Comment: It's not that it comes on and off the rim just by moving the wheel. It's just that I didn't need to use any tyre lever at all, just pushing with the palms of my hands was enough, but I remember in the past (other bikes), sometimes really needing to use the three tire levers to be able to put it on.

Comment: @myradio yep, some tires can be installed by hand with no levers.

Comment: ... and many tyres are excruciatingly hard to fit even with proper tools!